# Grub drops to shell after update

Tags: boot, grub2, kubuntu, btrfs

Kubuntu 19.04, updated as of May 17th.

This morning I ran updates on my Kubuntu installation, and after reboot, grub drops me to grub shell without giving me my grub menu.  This has happened to me a few times over the last few months, and I end up just re-installing because I gave up trying to figure out how to fix it.  But I'm at this point again, and I would like to figure out what's causing this.

Hardware:

- AMD Ryzen 2600X
- 16GB Ram
- Asus B450 Motherboard
- 1x Samsung Evo 500 GB SSD (Primary drive)
- 1x Seagate 1TB HDD (Storage Drive)
- No other OS's

Manually entering the following at the grub screen allows my system to boot (obfuscated the UUID) and function normally:

> > insmod gzio
>
> > insmod part_gpt
>
> > insmod btrfs
>
> >linux /@/boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-15-generic root=UUID=0000000-000-000 ro
>               rootflags=subvol=@ quiet splash
>
> > initrd /@/boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-15-generic
>
> > boot

But, this is obviously annoying to have to do every reboot.  I've checked my configuration files, everything looks fine, but it just seems like grub cannot read the configuration files for some reason.

The UUID for my primary drive has been obfuscated below, but I did verify that it is accurate in my configuration files.

/etc/fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=4DD8-BE9A  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda2 during installation
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0

UUID=0000000-000-000 /               btrfs   rw,relatime,compress=zstd,ssd,discard,space_cache,subvol=@ 0       1
UUID=0000000-000-000 /home           btrfs   rw,relatime,compress=zstd,ssd,discard,space_cache,subvol=@home 0       2
UUID=0000000-000-000 /var           btrfs   rw,relatime,compress=zstd,ssd,discard,space_cache,subvol=@var 0       2

UUID=1111111-111-111 /mnt/storage        btrfs   rw,relatime,compress=zstd,ssd,discard,space_cache 0 2
```

/boot/grub/grub.cfg

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${initrdfail}" = 2 ]; then
   set initrdfail=
elif [ "${initrdfail}" = 1 ]; then
   set next_entry="${prev_entry}"
   set prev_entry=
   save_env prev_entry
   if [ "${next_entry}" ]; then
      set initrdfail=2
   fi
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function initrdfail {
    if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -n "${partuuid}" ]; then
      if [ -z "${initrdfail}" ]; then
        set initrdfail=1
        if [ -n "${boot_once}" ]; then
          set prev_entry="${default}"
          save_env prev_entry
        fi
      fi
      save_env initrdfail
    fi; fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  # GRUB lacks write support for btrfs, so recordfail support is disabled.
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_gpt
insmod btrfs
set root='hd0,gpt2'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  60000000-000-000
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0000000-000-000
fi
    font="/@/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_CA
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=30
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=menu
    set timeout=1
  # Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  else
    set timeout=1
  fi
fi
if [ $grub_platform = efi ]; then
  set timeout=30
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=menu
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
#set_background_image "images/tile.png";

set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 0,0,0; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
        set gfxpayload="${1}"
        if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
                set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=1
        else
                set vt_handoff=
        fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-0000000-000-000' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod btrfs
        set root='hd0,gpt2'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  0000000-000-000
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0000000-000-000
        fi
        linux   /@/boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-15-generic root=UUID=0000000-000-000 ro rootflags=subvol=@  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        initrd  /@/boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-15-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-0000000-000-000' {
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.0.0-15-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.0.0-15-generic-advanced-0000000-000-000' {
                recordfail
                load_video
                gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
                insmod gzio
                if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
                insmod part_gpt
                insmod btrfs
                set root='hd0,gpt2'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  0000000-000-000
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0000000-000-000
                fi
                echo    'Loading Linux 5.0.0-15-generic ...'
                linux   /@/boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-15-generic root=UUID=0000000-000-000 ro rootflags=subvol=@  quiet splash $vt_handoff
                echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
                initrd  /@/boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-15-generic
        }
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.0.0-15-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.0.0-15-generic-recovery-0000000-000-000' {
                recordfail
                load_video
                insmod gzio
                if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
                insmod part_gpt
                insmod btrfs
                set root='hd0,gpt2'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  60000000-000-000
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0000000-000-000
                fi
                echo    'Loading Linux 5.0.0-15-generic ...'
                linux   /@/boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-15-generic root=UUID=0000000-000-000 ro recovery nomodeset rootflags=subvol=@ 
                echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
                initrd  /@/boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-15-generic
        }
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.0.0-13-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.0.0-13-generic-advanced-698b5d59-0000000-000-000' {
                recordfail
                load_video
                gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
                insmod gzio
                if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
                insmod part_gpt
                insmod btrfs
                set root='hd0,gpt2'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  0000000-000-000
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0000000-000-000
                fi
                echo    'Loading Linux 5.0.0-13-generic ...'
                linux   /@/boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-13-generic root=UUID=0000000-000-000 ro rootflags=subvol=@  quiet splash $vt_handoff
                echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
                initrd  /@/boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-13-generic
        }
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.0.0-13-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.0.0-13-generic-recovery-0000000-000-000' {
                recordfail
                load_video
                insmod gzio
                if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
                insmod part_gpt
                insmod btrfs
                set root='hd0,gpt2'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  0000000-000-000
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0000000-000-000
                fi
                echo    'Loading Linux 5.0.0-13-generic ...'
                linux   /@/boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-13-generic root=UUID=0000000-000-000 ro recovery nomodeset rootflags=subvol=@ 
                echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
                initrd  /@/boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-13-generic
        }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
menuentry 'System setup' $menuentry_id_option 'uefi-firmware' {
        fwsetup
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

/etc/default/grub

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=1
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Nothing in /etc/grub/grub.d except empty (commented out) init-select.cfg

Output of update-grub:

```
~# update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-15-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-15-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-13-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-13-generic
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

Output of fdisk:

```
~# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 850 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 222222222-2222-2222222

Device      Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1    2048    999423    997376   487M EFI System
/dev/sda2  999424 976771071 975771648 465.3G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sdb: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: ST31000524AS    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 33333333333-3333-3333333

Device     Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048 1953519615 1953517568 931.5G Linux filesystem
```

Contents of /boot/efi

```
# find /boot/efi
/boot/efi
/boot/efi/EFI
/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu
/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/BOOTX64.CSV
/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg
/boot/efi/EFI/BOOT
/boot/efi/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI
/boot/efi/EFI/BOOT/fbx64.efi
/boot/efi/EFI/BOOT/mmx64.efi
```

I'm not sure what else I can look at here unless someone has any suggestions?

**Edit:**  I have a laptop that has a very similar setup to this (my desktop), and it is not having the same issue.  The one notable difference that I can see is in the /boot/grub/grub.cfg file, my laptop doesn't have the "set root='hd0,gpt2'" line for the grub menuentry.  Not sure if that's related or not, but it wouldn't explain why I just don't get the menu at all.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this myself with the following:

```
# grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootloader=ubuntu -recheck
# update-grub
# update-initramfs -u
```

Curious on why this happened after an update.